# Transit visa for Amsterdam & Paris

Tags: visas

I am Indian holding an Indian passport, travelling to Colombia for a business visit via Amsterdam and Paris. I am a resident of South Korea, having valid visas for Korea and Colombia. Do I need a transit visa for Amsterdam and Paris?

Amsterdam layover: 3 hours, and Paris 5 hours.

Comment: @ugoren if the Amsterdam layover is on the way to Colombia, and the Paris layover on the way back (or the other way around), then a visitor visa isn't necessary, but an airport transit visa will be needed.

Comment: @phoog, Yes, the question is ambiguous. I assumed `???->AMS->PAR->COL->BOG->PAR->AMS->???`, but it may be `???->AMS->BOG->PAR->???`. Deleting my comment. Hopefully the OP will read the duplicate's answer and figure it out.

Comment: Onward to Colombia (SEOUL-AMS-PAR-BOG) and Return (BOG-PAR-SEOUL)